# Create a new column with non-null columns' names

Tags: r, data.table

My data set looks like this one:

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 b = c(1,0,2,5,1),
                 c = c(0,1,1,0,0),
                 d = c(1,0,0,2,2))

df
#    a b c d
# 1: 1 1 0 1
# 2: 2 0 1 0
# 3: 3 2 1 0
# 4: 4 5 0 2
# 5: 5 1 0 2
```

I want to create a new column with non-null columns names. The result will be:

```
df_result <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                        z = c('b_d', 'c', 'b_c', 'b_d', 'b_d'))

df_result
#    a   z
# 1: 1 b_d
# 2: 2   c
# 3: 3 b_c
# 4: 4 b_d
# 5: 5 b_d
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option would be to convert the format from 'wide' to 'long' using `melt`.  Grouped by 'a', we `paste` the 'variable' elements that corresponds to non-zero elements in 'value' (provided as logical condition in 'i').

```
melt(df, id.var='a')[value!=0, 
      .(z=paste(variable, collapse="_")), keyby =a]
#   a   z
#1: 1 b_d
#2: 2   c
#3: 3 b_c
#4: 4 b_d
#5: 5 b_d
```

---

Or instead of `melt`ing, we can group by 'a', `unlist` the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) and `paste` the `names` of the columns that corresponds to non-zero elements ('i1').

```
df[, {i1 <- !!unlist(.SD)
       paste(names(.SD)[i1], collapse="_")} , by= a]
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.table(a=1:1e6, b = sample(0:5, 1e6, 
   replace=TRUE), c = sample(0:4, 1e6, replace=TRUE), 
    d = sample(0:3, 1e6, replace=TRUE))

akrun1 <- function() {
   melt(df1, id.var='a')[value!=0, 
      .(z=paste(variable, collapse="_")), keyby =a]
    }

 akrun2 <- function() {
   df1[, {i1 <- !!unlist(.SD)
       paste(names(.SD)[i1], collapse="_")} , by= a]
   }

 ronak <- function() {
    data.table(z = lapply(apply(df1, 1, function(x)
                which(x[-1]!= 0)), 
       function(x) paste0(names(x), collapse = "_")))
   }

eddi <- function(){
 df1[, newcol := gsub("NA_|_NA|NA", "",                          
   do.call(function(...) paste(..., sep = "_"),            
     Map(function(x, y) x[(y == 0) + 1], names(.SD), .SD)))
 , .SDcols = b:d]

 }

alexis = function(x)
   {
   ans = character(nrow(x))
   for(j in seq_along(x)) {
    i = x[[j]] > 0L
    ans[i] = paste(ans[i], names(x)[[j]], sep = "_")
   }
  return(gsub("^_", "", ans))
}





system.time(akrun1())
#   user  system elapsed 
#  22.04    0.15   22.36 
 system.time(akrun2())
#   user  system elapsed 
# 26.33    0.00   26.41 
 system.time(ronak())
#   user  system elapsed 
#  25.60    0.26   25.96 


system.time(alexis(df1[, -1L, with = FALSE]))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.92    0.06    2.09 

system.time(eddi())
#  user  system elapsed 
#   2.41    0.06    3.19
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the same, but we need to point out that this is still iterating over each row of the original data.table. For a large data.table it's probably not very fast and it might be better to avoid the `melt` and just iterate over the rows.

Comment: Yes, these both solutions run almost 2 minutes on my machine on a 1e7 data set. The `apply` solution runs not much longer

Comment: @DavidArenburg I thought `unlist` will be a bit faster.  Have you checked the timings with `apply`

Comment: why not `keyby=a`?

Comment: yes, the `apply` one runs about 20-30 seconds longer.

Comment: @akrun please add benchmarks for the other two answers as well

Comment: @akrun uhm ok, if I had any desire to do that, it'd be done long ago. You can improve *your* answer, since, as-is it contains the benchmarks for the slowest answers, and omits two much faster ones.

Comment: @akrun thanks for adding the benchmarks (fwiw I don't think "first" matters, but this answer is fine imo - perhaps the downvotes are due to attitude?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107876/discussion-between-eddi-and-akrun).

Answer (score 12):

Assuming `nrow >> ncol`, you could work columnwise

```
ff = function(x)
{
    ans = character(nrow(x))
    for(j in seq_along(x)) {
        i = x[[j]] > 0L
        ans[i] = paste(ans[i], names(x)[[j]], sep = "_")
    }
    return(gsub("^_", "", ans))
}
ff(df[, -1L, with = FALSE]) #or, `df[, ff(.SD), .SDcols = -1L]` from David Arenburg
#[1] "b_d" "c"   "b_c" "b_d" "b_d"
```

Comment: Oh, this neat. I was waiting for you to post something. I would guess `df[, ff(.SD), .SDcols = -1]` will perform a bit better.

Comment: @DavidArenburg : I saw traffic on the 'data.table' tag and tried to squeeze a few upvotes..... I benchmarked your idea, too; performance of both seems similar.

Comment: Yes, but you could do stuff like `df[, z := ff(.SD), .SDcols = -1]` and avoid deep copies, unlike with your original solution- because `with = FALSE` always makes a deep copy.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a direct approach:

```
df[, newcol := gsub("NA_|_NA|NA", "",                           # remove unwanted text
       do.call(function(...) paste(..., sep = "_"),             # paste colnames together
         Map(function(x, y) x[(y == 0) + 1], names(.SD), .SD))) # convert data to colnames
   , .SDcols = b:d]
#   a b c d newcol
#1: 1 1 0 1    b_d
#2: 2 0 1 0      c
#3: 3 2 1 0    b_c
#4: 4 5 0 2    b_d
#5: 5 1 0 2    b_d
```

On akrun's test data it's >10x faster.

Answer (score 4):

This can be a bit lengthy.

For every row finding a column whose value is not 0 and then pasting the column names together.

```
data.table(a= df$a, z = lapply(apply(df, 1, 
           function(x) which(x[-1]!= 0)), 
           function(x) paste0(names(x), collapse = "_")))


#   a   z
#1: 1 b_d
#2: 2   c
#3: 3 b_c
#4: 4 b_d
#5: 5 b_d
```

Comment: This is just converting the `data.table` to a matrix and doing by row operations. There is nothing related to `data.table`  in this solution.

Comment: Although using `data.table` is fast in most of the cases, I am not well acquainted with `data.table`. Further, I think nowhere in the question the OP suggested to use only `data.table` hence, the attempt.

Comment: The tags under the question are relevant here.

Comment: You benched it on 5 rows?

Comment: Nice solution, but what about column `a`? currently it doesn't precisely answer the question. This may be the reason why OP won't accept it as answer so I would definitely work on that. Benchmark on 5 rows isn't a benchmark really :)

Comment: @jangorecki I thought, getting the `z` column is more important. Anyways, there is no harm in being perfect. Thank you. Updated!

Comment: @RonakShah and what about benchmark? it doesn't make sense to show benchmark for 5 rows :/