# Skip paste0 entry when value is zero for the entry itself and entry before entry is 0

Tags: r, string

I have one problem using the `paste0` function. I have a data frame:
data:

```
    C  C13 H O N
1   1   0  4 0 0
2   2   0  4 0 0
3   3   0  4 0 0
4   4   0  4 0 0
5   5   0  4 1 0
6   1   1  4 1 0
7   2   1  4 1 1
```

using

```
data$formula = paste0("C", data$C, "C13", data$C13, "H", data$H, "O", data$O, "N",data$N)
```

I get the formula column

```
    C  C13 H O N       formula
1   1   0  4 0 0  C1C130H4O0N0
2   2   0  4 0 0  C2C130H4O0N0
3   3   0  4 0 0  C3C130H4O0N0
4   4   0  4 0 0  C4C130H4O0N0
5   5   0  4 1 0  C5C130H4O1N0
6   1   1  4 1 0  C1C131H4O1N0
7   2   1  4 1 1  C2C131H4O1N1
```

The problem is that I want all strings that have 0 value out,so for row 1 I want to have: `C1H4` instead of `C1C130H4O0N0` and so on.

I am really new to R so I tried

```
data$formula = paste0("C", data$C>0, "C13", data$C13>0, "H", data$H>0, "O", data$O>0, "N",data$N>0)
```

but this gives me only true false output...

Could anyone help me here, please or has an idea how to solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could find helpful [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304404/create-a-new-column-with-non-null-columns-names) or, also, [this recent one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755021/r-function-categorize-by-column) after slight modifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just a single apply should be enough I suppose !

Logic : first we are iterating through each row using `apply(df, 1, ...)` ; Then we check which all entries are non-zero using `which` ; Once you get the indices, just subset the respective colnames and values

```
df$formula <- apply(df, 1, function(x){y = which(x!=0) 
                                       paste0(colnames(df)[y], x[y], collapse = "")})
# [1] "C1H4"         "C2H4"         "C3H4"         "C4H4"         "C5H4O1"       "C1C131H4O1"   "C2C131H4O1N1" 

> df
#  C C13 H O N      formula
#1 1   0 4 0 0         C1H4
#2 2   0 4 0 0         C2H4
#3 3   0 4 0 0         C3H4
#4 4   0 4 0 0         C4H4
#5 5   0 4 1 0       C5H4O1
#6 1   1 4 1 0   C1C131H4O1
#7 2   1 4 1 1 C2C131H4O1N1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, both of you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
> apply(apply(data, 1, function(x) ifelse(x>0, paste0(names(data), x), '')), 2, paste0, collapse='')
             1              2              3              4              5              6              7 
        "C1H4"         "C2H4"         "C3H4"         "C4H4"       "C5H4O1"   "C1C131H4O1" "C2C131H4O1N1"
```

This can be assigned back to the column in the data frame.

The inner `apply` does the `>0` selection:

```
> apply(data, 1, function(x) ifelse(x>0, paste0(names(data), x), ''))
    1    2    3    4    5    6      7     
C   "C1" "C2" "C3" "C4" "C5" "C1"   "C2"  
C13 ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   "C131" "C131"
H   "H4" "H4" "H4" "H4" "H4" "H4"   "H4"  
O   ""   ""   ""   ""   "O1" "O1"   "O1"  
N   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""     "N1"
```

The outer `apply` pastes the columns of this result together to get the final output.