# Extract column names with value 1 in binary matrix

Tags: r, matrix, binary

I have a problem; i would like to create a new matrix starting from a binary matrix structured like this:

```
  A B C D E F
G 0 0 1 1 0 0
H 0 0 0 1 1 0
I 0 0 0 0 1 0
L 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

i want to create a **new matrix** made by row names of the starting one, and a new and unique column, called X, which contains for every rows, the name/names of the column every time the correspondent matrix number is 1.

How could i do?

Comment: See [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304404/create-a-new-column-with-non-null-columns-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this where `m` is your matrix:

```
as.matrix(apply(m==1,1,function(a) paste0(colnames(m)[a], collapse = "")))

#  [,1]
#G "CD"
#H "DE"
#I "E" 
#L "AB"
```

Another option which *might* be faster if `m` is large:

```
t <- which(m==1, arr.ind = TRUE)
as.matrix(aggregate(col~row, cbind(row=rownames(t), col=t[,2]), function(x) 
                                                    paste0(colnames(m)[x], collapse = "")))
```

Comment: I tested the time taken for a matrix of dim `1e+5 x 100` and the first approach is much faster.