# Extract column names & combine them with delimiter if value =1 (binary values) and put it in new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with binary values post performing get_dummies using pandas

```
df= 
Values  A1  A2  B1  B2  B3  B4  C1  C2  C3
10      1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
12      0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
3       0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1
5       1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
```

I want a new column which has combination of all columns which has 1's in it

```
Expected output:

Values  A1  A2  B1  B2  B3  B4  C1  C2  C3  Combination
10      1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   A1~~B1~~C1
12      0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   A2~~B3~~C2
3       0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   A2~~B2~~C3
5       1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   A1~~B4~~C3
```

Actual matrix can be 25000+ rows*1000+columns

There is a similar solution found in R but i need it in Python bcoz all other dependencies are in python and R is new to me.

[Extract column names with value 1 in binary matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44585712/extract-column-names-with-value-1-in-binary-matrix)

```
Codes in R below, & need similar one or any other code in python which can help me to arrive at my expected output
Solution 1 : 
as.matrix(apply(m==1,1,function(a) paste0(colnames(m)[a], collapse = "")))

Solution 2: 
t <- which(m==1, arr.ind = TRUE)
as.matrix(aggregate(col~row, cbind(row=rownames(t), col=t[,2]), function(x) 
                                                    paste0(colnames(m)[x], collapse = "")))
```

how could something similar or arrive at my expected output in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df["Combination"] = df.iloc[:, 1:].dot(df.add_suffix("~~").columns[1:]).str[:-2]
```

We select columns except for `Values` with `iloc` and then form a dot product where the second operand is respective columns of `df` with `~~` added to the end. Result gives `~~` for the very end as well, so we chop it with `.str[:-2]`

to get

```
   Values  A1  A2  B1  B2  B3  B4  C1  C2  C3 Combination
0      10   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0  A1~~B1~~C1
1      12   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0  A2~~B3~~C2
2       3   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1  A2~~B2~~C3
3       5   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0  A1~~B4~~C1
```

Comment: imho, this is an ideal solution since it avoids using `apply`. However, since it needs a 2nd string-stripping step, it would have to be timed against the `apply solution`. This would probably still be faster.

Comment: Btw, you can skip the `.values` part before `.dot` so that it produces a pandas Series. And then you can put the string trimming in the same step: `df.iloc[:, 1:].dot(df.add_suffix("~~").columns[1:]).str[:-2]`

Answer (score 5):

You can try [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
df["Combination"] = df.drop("Values", axis=1).apply(lambda x: "~~".join(x[x != 0].index), axis=1)

print(df)
#    Values  A1  A2  B1  B2  B3  B4  C1  C2  C3 Combination
# 0      10   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0  A1~~B1~~C1
# 1      12   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0  A2~~B3~~C2
# 2       3   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1  A2~~B2~~C3
# 3       5   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0  A1~~B4~~C1
```

**Explanations**:

1. For calculating the  `Combination`, ignore `Values` column. Several approach are possible (see this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940743/selecting-excluding-sets-of-columns-in-pandas)). Here I use [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html): `df.drop("Values", axis=1)`.
2. Apply a custom function over each row using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and `axis=1`
3. In the function, filter values different from `0` using `x[x != 0]`
4. Select column name (here there are index of the Serie) using [`.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.index.html)
5. Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to match desired output: `"~~".join(x[x != 0].index)`

---

**Full illustration**:

```
# Step 1
print(df.drop("Values", axis=1))
#    A1  A2  B1  B2  B3  B4  C1  C2  C3
# 0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
# 1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
# 2   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1
# 3   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0

# Step 3
print(df.drop("Values", axis=1).apply(lambda x: x[x != 0], axis=1))
#     A1   A2   B1   B2   B3   B4   C1   C2   C3
# 0  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
# 1  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
# 2  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
# 3  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN

# Step 4
print(df.drop("Values", axis=1).apply(lambda x: x[x != 0].index, axis=1))
# 0    Index(['A1', 'B1', 'C1'], dtype='object')
# 1    Index(['A2', 'B3', 'C2'], dtype='object')
# 2    Index(['A2', 'B2', 'C3'], dtype='object')
# 3    Index(['A1', 'B4', 'C1'], dtype='object')

# Step 5
df["Combination"] = df.drop("Values", axis=1).apply(lambda x: "~~".join(x[x != 0].index), axis=1)
print(df)
#    Values  A1  A2  B1  B2  B3  B4  C1  C2  C3 Combination
# 0      10   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0  A1~~B1~~C1
# 1      12   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0  A2~~B3~~C2
# 2       3   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1  A2~~B2~~C3
# 3       5   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0  A1~~B4~~C1
```

Comment: i  can't help but upvote for such a detailed explanation, i wish more answers here would be like this...

Comment: Hopefully that will help, thank you @MustafaAydın :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `.dot` function of pandas after dropping your `values` column to get the column names you want and then process the output with list comprehensions to obtain the right `A1~~B1~~C1` format.

Here's what it looks looks like:

```
tmp = [list(i) for i in list(df.dot(df.columns))]
df['combination'] = ['~~'.join(i) for i in tmp]

print(df)

    A   B   C   D   combination
0   1   1   0   0   A~~B
1   0   1   1   0   B~~C
2   0   0   1   0   C
```

Comment: Spoke too soon. This solution has an issue if the columns have more than one character in the name. Gives outputs like `A~~1~~B~~1~~C~~1` instead of `A1~~B1~~C1`.